# Return on scroll firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

I've created a sticky sidebar function which works perfectly in chrome and safari but not in Firefox. From what I can tell it's not returning properly when it should be.

Consider a snippet of the code in question:

```
            if (scrolling_down && bottom_offset <= bottom_padding) {
                $item.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 'auto',
                    bottom: bottom_padding
                });

                console.log(1);

                return false;

                console.log(2);
            }

            console.log(3);
```

The console in Chrome logs `3` until it hits the bottom of the page then logs `1` for the rest of the scroll.

In Firefox however, the console logs `3` until it hits the bottom then alternates between `3` and `1`.

I'm pretty sure it should be ignoring 3 (because of the `return false`) once it's hit the bottom, like Chrome.

Full Javascript:

```
    // Sticky Sidebars
    stickyAsides: function() {
        var $item = $('.js-sticky'),
            $parent = $item.parent(),

            last_scroll = 0,
            scrolling_down = false;

        function setStyles() {
            $item.css({
                width: $item.outerWidth()
            });
        }

        function stick() {
            var parent_rect = $parent.get(0).getBoundingClientRect(),
                parent_top = parent_rect.top,
                parent_bottom = parent_rect.bottom,

                item_rect = $item.get(0).getBoundingClientRect(),
                item_top = item_rect.top,
                item_bottom = item_rect.bottom,

                bottom_offset = parent_bottom - item_bottom,
                bottom_padding = parseInt($parent.css('padding-bottom'));

            scrolling_down = (last_scroll < w.scroll) ? true : false;

            setStyles();

            if (scrolling_down && bottom_offset <= bottom_padding) {
                $item.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 'auto',
                    bottom: bottom_padding
                });

                console.log(1);

                return false;

                console.log(2);
            }

            console.log(3);

            if (item_top <= -10 || parent_top <= 0) {
                $item.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '0',
                    bottom: 'auto'
                });
            }

            if (!scrolling_down && parent_top > 0) {
                $item.css({
                    position: 'relative',
                    top: '0',
                    bottom: 'auto'
                });
            }

            last_scroll = w.scroll;

        }

        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            w.scroll = $doc.scrollTop();

            if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 1024px)') && Modernizr.flexbox) {
                stick();
            }
        });
    }, // End stickyAsides()
```

EDIT: Codepen Example: http://codepen.io/jhealey5/pen/JGLjPN - However this seems to work okay, so there is something else interfering on the page. I don't expect anyone to solve it but there might be some advice. I'm unable to link to the live page at this time I'm afraid.

Comment: Hard to tell without a working plunkr or jsbin example that also shows the HTML. But what's wrong with `position: fixed`?

Comment: It has to stick when NOT hitting the top/bottom of the page. Otherwise it should be relative for top, and absolute positioning for bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Firefox wasn't doing calculations correctly. Adding +20px to the bottom padding calculation seems to fix it.